# Linux C: mount() fails with EPERM

Tags: c, linux

On RHEL6, I'm trying to mount a file system as non-superuser (abc_admin). I think I have all the permissions set properly, but I'm still getting permission error.

Here are the permissions on my block device:

```
brw-rw----. 1 abc_admin abc_admin 8, 5 Oct 10 09:25 /dev/sda5
```

Here are the permissions on the mount directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x.   2 abc_admin abc_admin  4096 Oct  8 12:49 mount
```

Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    int stat = mount("/dev/sda5", "/mount", "ext4", 0, "");
    if (0 != stat) {
        perror("mount failed");
        exit(5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is strace:

```
mount("/dev/sda5", "/mount", "ext4", 0, "") = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
brk(0)                                  = 0x1416000
brk(0x1437000)                          = 0x1437000
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 6), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f479bf3e000
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
write(3, "mount failed: Operation not perm"..., 38mount failed: Operation not permitted
) = 38
close(3)
```

Comment: In the second line, did you check `/mount` or `./mount` (current directory)?  Also, does this work as root?

Comment: Check the system log - are there any SELinux errors?

Comment: It's not about permission of /mount directory, it's about whether you've capabilities to execute mount() system call. man page says you need "CAP_SYS_ADMIN" to mount a file system.

Answer (score 3):

Can you call `mount` from the command line as that user? In Linux, you generally need at least `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` in order to be able to mount filesystems. Does you have have `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` when running this, or does the executable have `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` set on it? You can check if the executable has the capability with `getcap myexe`, and set it with `setcap cap_sys_admin+ep myexe` (of course, you need to do this as root), or you could just make it suid root: `chown root:root myexe; chmod u+s myexe`.

If you don't have `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` and the executable is not suid root, then you can only mount filesystems that are defined in `/etc/fstab` with the `user` option. For example:

```
/dev/cdrom  /cd  iso9660  ro,user,noauto,unhide
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually only the super-user "root" is allowed to mount filesystems, otherwise it would be a huge security hole (unless precautions are taken like mounting with "nodev" and "nosuid").